# Name of area around a light

Tags: word-request

When a person looks at light he sees this thing around it and a streak of some sort. What is it?

I found **gloom**, **glow**, and **flare** but am not sure if they are it.

Comment: [**Halo**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/halo) *- a circle of white or coloured light around the sun, moon, or other luminous body caused by refraction through ice crystals in the atmosphere.* Or caused by cataracts and other vision defects.

Comment: Do you have a picture of what you mean?

Comment: @tamayura I don't think a camera can show this effect, I guess it's eye effect only.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think it is it.

Comment: I'm imagining something like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/3f/Halo_phantom-sun.jpg/317px-Halo_phantom-sun.jpg

Comment: The word that occurs to me is [**glare**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/glare): "a harsh uncomfortably bright light"   In practice I think the meaning is a little more poetic than that, though - we often refer to things like "the glare of the streetlights" even though streetlights are not really that bright.

Answer (score 1):

You might be thinking of the effect called "lens flare".  Check out this article for examples:  [Every Single Star Trek Lens Flare, Ever](http://io9.gizmodo.com/every-single-star-trek-lens-flare-ever-1681140320).

Comment: A lens flare occurs only when you look through a lens right? What about eyes, do they see it?

Comment: @SovereignSun - technically, I don't think eyes have lens flare, because lens flare is caused by internal reflections between different elements of a camera lens, and your eyeballs aren't built the same way, but there is definitely something similar.